# Eclipse Unhandled Exception

Tags: eclipse

I have a SSD with a arch Linux distribution on it and use it for my computer and my laptop. when I am programming on my computer everything works fine, but when I start eclipse on my laptop and switch between classes a `Unhandled event loop exception\n No more handles` error window pops up.

Here is the stack trace:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4559)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4448)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4419)
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Cursor.<init>(Cursor.java:173)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getSystemCursor(Display.java:2688)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon.DragAgent.dragFinished(DragAgent.java:157)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon.PartDragAgent.dragFinished(PartDragAgent.java:93)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon.DnDManager.finishDrag(DnDManager.java:285)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon.DnDManager.startDrag(DnDManager.java:252)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon.DnDManager$1.dragDetected(DnDManager.java:89)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:128)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5227)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1340)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4561)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4151)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:693)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
```

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?